# Laravel count using eloquent between two tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a Answer Model

```
 public function upvote_answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UpvoteAnswer');
    }
```

And I also have a UpvoteAnswer Model

```
public function answer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Answer');
    }
```

I have a table which is named upvote_answers which has column such as **id**, **user_id**, **answer_id**(a different answers table, this id is referencing to that table), and **upvote**(which is boolean 1 or 0)

I want a count of upvote and downvote for individual answers so i have done like this

```
$answer = UpvoteAnswer::find($answerid) ;
$counting = $answer->upvote_answers->count();
echo $counting;
```

i was trying to echo total count for one answer but this doesn't seem to work, I am trying to do eager load , how can i build this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer Model:**

```
public function upvote_answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UpvoteAnswer', 'answer_id', 'id')->where('upvote', 1);
}

public function downvote_answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UpvoteAnswer', 'answer_id', 'id')->where('upvote', 0);
}
```

Then you can count like this:

```
$upvote = $answer->upvote_answers->count();
$downvote = $answer->downvote_answers->count();
```

Comment: if it's solve your problem, mark it as answer please

Comment: this doesn't work , it says Trying to get property of non-object